# How do I convert this ASP.NET Webforms example to MVC5 razor compatible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an example of how to include a resource into MVC, but it's ASP.NET Webforms. I'm not sure how to convert this to MVC razor form. I've made several attempts. Pretty sure the `<%=` gets replaced with `@` but that's going to mess up the `"` groupings.

```
<script src="<%= Westwind.Globalization.JavaScriptResourceHandler.GetJavaScriptResourcesUrl("globalRes","CodePasteMvc.Resources.Resources")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%=` gets replaced with `@` 
and `"` groupings are not converted. they remains the same. Razor is smart to handle that

For more Info about converting [***Click Here***](http://beletsky.net/2011/07/switching-from-aspx-to-razor-view.html)

Your Code is already correct

```
<script src=" @Westwind.Globalization.JavaScriptResourceHandler.GetJavaScriptResourcesUrl("globalRes","CodePasteMvc.Resources.Resources")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```